# Sql combination from and to a single table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a single table looking like this:

Table extract

```
    Owner   | Attribute | value
----------------------------------------------------
    10      | COLOR     | BLUE
    10      | COLOR     | RED
    10      | COLOR     | GREEN
    10      | SIZE      | BIG
    20      | COLOR     | GREEN
    20      | SIZE      | MEDIUM
    20      | MEMORY    | 16G
    20      | MEMORY    | 32G
    30      | COLOR     | RED
    30      | COLOR     | BLUE
    30      | MEMORY    | 64G
```

Is there a SQL which will calculate a combination of all attribute with a single index (last column in the result):

```
Owner   | Attribute | Value | Rule_No
10      | COLOR     | BLUE  | 1
10      | SIZE      | BIG   | 1
10      | COLOR     | RED   | 2
10      | SIZE      | BIG   | 2
10      | COLOR     | GREEN | 3
10      | SIZE      | BIG   | 3
20      | COLOR     | GREEN | 1
20      | SIZE      | MEDIUM| 1
20      | MEMORY    | 16G   | 1
20      | COLOR     | GREEN | 2
20      | SIZE      | MEDIUM| 2
20      | MEMORY    | 32G   | 2
30      | COLOR     | BLUE  | 1
30      | MEMORY    | 64G   | 1
30      | COLOR     | RED   | 2
30      | MEMORY    | 64G   | 2
```

The rule number would be unique per owner (rule '1' for owner '10' is not related to rule '1' for owner '20'.

I tried to use the SQL cross join, but the number of attributes is not fixed, then I cannot use it (one cross join per attribute is needed) and I want the combination to be new rows instead new columns.

I am trying to use `Talend Open Studio - Data Integration` to do it but a solution using only SQL would be better for me.

Comment: Why, for instance does 10|COLOR|BLUE = 1 and 10|COLOR|RED = 2?

Comment: No single SQL statement can do what you are trying to get. You need to build a stored procedure.

Comment: Wow. I don't even understand what the OP's trying to get!

Comment: This looks like a permutation question, i.e. all combinations of available attributes

Comment: Why 10:green:Big has RuleNo=2. I guess it have to be 3?

Comment: @Strawberry: why... because this is the poorly auto-generated data from the product I use. Generally it means that all product which are RED or BLUE or GREEN and the size is BIG have to follow some rules.

Comment: @valex, thanks you are right it was a typo...

Comment: @Andromar, I do not know what is the permutation, but the order is not important and the resulting combination should appears only once ( e.g COLOR/SIZE = SIZE/COLOR).

Comment: I think it was explained very well, interesting question.  That said I don't have an answer for you.

Comment: Would you be so kind to explain how did you set rule_no? Just don't get it...

Comment: The Rule # is the combination(s) for a specific owner. There are 3 possible combinations for owner 10, 2 for owner 20, and 2 for owner 30.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy you understood what I want to do, and the answer to Andrey is exactly that.

Comment: I found a solution but is is built partially in mySQL and with specific java code in Talend DI... I am not specifically looking for a full SQL solution anyway. I will publish my solution when I am sure it is working.

Comment: Does mysql has a rowid / tupleid / tidp ? [the row_number() OVER can be emulated using such a construct]

Comment: Is a stored procedure an option?

Comment: For me anything that does the job is an option; my own solution I am building is built on a SQL query + a big Java Processing + Talend ETL processes (normalization).

Comment: @voxenv: there's absolutely no challenge in this if you allow for cursors, stored procedures or wrapper code. In procedural code, all you do is 1) get table (per owner if large dataset) 2) determine number of sets 3) build list of sets & per-attribute values 4) populate sets 5) write to database.

Comment: @Stu: I am not asking this question for a challenge but I had such data to process in any way (real situation). When doing consulting you do whatever drives you on a solution as long the language(s) used complies with the customer's standards.

Comment: @voxenv: a lot of people here answer questions because they are a challenge -- we're not consulting here :)  -- anyway, "a simple SQL statement will suffice" threw me off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you *really* want the data in the form given in your question (which would then require further aggregation on `Rule_No` to be useful in most likely situations), or are you ultimately seeking to pivot it?  That is, rules are joined together (with each attribute becoming its own column) as follows:

```
+---------+-------+-------+--------+--------+
| Rule_No | Owner | COLOR | SIZE   | MEMORY |
+---------+-------+-------+--------+--------+
|       1 |    10 | BLUE  | BIG    | NULL   |
|       2 |    10 | RED   | BIG    | NULL   |
|       3 |    10 | GREEN | BIG    | NULL   |
|       1 |    20 | GREEN | MEDIUM | 16G    |
|       2 |    20 | GREEN | MEDIUM | 32G    |
|       1 |    30 | RED   | NULL   | 64G    |
|       2 |    30 | BLUE  | NULL   | 64G    |
+---------+-------+-------+--------+--------+
```

One can pivot such data with a query as follows:

```
SELECT   @t:=IF(Owner=@o,@t,0)+1 AS Rule_No,
         @o:=Owner AS Owner,
         `COLOR`,`SIZE`,`MEMORY`
FROM     (SELECT DISTINCT Owner, @t:=0 FROM my_table) t0

  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Owner, value AS `COLOR`
    FROM   my_table
    WHERE  Attribute='COLOR'
  ) AS `t_COLOR` USING (Owner)

  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Owner, value AS `SIZE`
    FROM   my_table
    WHERE  Attribute='SIZE'
  ) AS `t_SIZE` USING (Owner)

  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Owner, value AS `MEMORY`
    FROM   my_table
    WHERE  Attribute='MEMORY'
  ) AS `t_MEMORY` USING (Owner)

ORDER BY Owner, Rule_No
```

As the attribute list is dynamic, one can use a query to construct the above SQL from which one prepares and executes a statement:

```
SELECT CONCAT('
         SELECT   @t:=IF(Owner=@o,@t,0)+1 AS Rule_No,
                  @o:=Owner AS Owner,
                  ', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(
                    '`',REPLACE(Attribute,'`','``'),'`'
                  )), '
         FROM     (SELECT DISTINCT Owner, @t:=0 FROM my_table) t0
       ', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('
           LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT Owner, value AS `',REPLACE(Attribute,'`','``'),'`
             FROM   my_table
             WHERE  Attribute=',QUOTE(Attribute),'
           ) AS `t_',REPLACE(Attribute,'`','``'),'` USING (Owner)
         ') SEPARATOR ''), '
         ORDER BY Owner, Rule_No
       ') INTO @sql
FROM   my_table;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2980c/1/2).

Comment: Question states `the number of attributes is not fixed`.

Comment: @ic3b3rg: Very well.  Replaced "*If the attribute list is dynamic, ...*" with "*As the attribute list is dynamic, ...*".

Comment: I should have looked closer at your solution - elegant if it the format is acceptable.

Comment: it looks like it always work, even if you add more data! the format is different than the expected result but it's very elegant, and if needed it's always possible to convert it back to rows... +1

Comment: Very nice. Pivot for the win (and bounty).

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so first before I write anything else: this query can be done in just one SQL select, but I won't recommend it. It may run for this small sample table, but it will not be a realistic solution to great tables, and it can be solved in a better (faster, cleaner) way by using stored procedures.

Also, I didn't finish it fully, because it't 2:10 AM here, and I already have a few hours of work in this - it was too much of a challenge not to think about, but the remaining parts are only copy-paste SQL rewrites based on the already existing query.

I posted my thought process with sample data on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/9MswhM3P)

The basic process is to:

1. count the possible permutations (N) for an owner
2. construct an SQL query, which generates numbers from 1..(N*number_of_attributes)
3. for every row

   1. select an attribute based on N
   2. select a value for the attribute based on N

This algorithm is a generic solution for any number of attributes or values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's fthiella's answer for SQL Server (NOT FINAL):

```
If  Object_ID('tempdb..#test') Is Not Null Drop Table #test;

Select '10' As Owner,'COLOR' Attribute,'BLUE' Value Into #test
Union
Select '10','COLOR','RED'
Union
Select '10','COLOR','GREEN'
Union
Select '10','SIZE','BIG'
Union
Select '20','a','1'
Union
Select '20','a','2'
Union
Select '20','b','111'
Union
Select '20','b','222'
Union
Select '20','COLOR','GREEN'
Union
Select '20','SIZE','MEDIUM'
Union
Select '20','MEMORY','16G'
Union
Select '20','MEMORY','32G'
Union
Select '30','COLOR','RED'
Union
Select '30','COLOR','BLUE'
Union
Select '30','MEMORY','64G';



Select 
    Owner, Attribute, Value,
    RuleNo = Row_Number() Over (Partition By Owner, Attribute Order By Owner, Attribute)
From
    (Select Base.Owner, Base.Attribute, Base.Value
    From
        #Test As Base
        Inner Join
            (Select Owner, Attribute
             From #Test
             Group By Owner, Attribute
             Having Count(*) > 1) As MultipleValue
        On Base.Owner = MultipleValue.Owner
        And Base.Attribute = MultipleValue.Attribute
        Union All
        Select Sing.Owner, Sing.Attribute, Sing.Value
        From
            (Select Owner, Attribute, Value = Min(Value)
            From #Test
            Group by Owner, Attribute
            Having Count(*) = 1) As Sing
        Inner Join
            (Select Owner, Attribute
            From #Test
            Group by Owner, Attribute
            Having Count(*) > 1) As Mult
            On Sing.Owner = Mult.Owner
        Inner Join #Test As Comp
        On Mult.Owner = Comp.Owner And Mult.Attribute = Comp.Attribute) As Vals
Order By 
    Owner, RuleNo, Attribute, Value
```

Comment: This is tagged as MySQL, there is no `row_number()`

Comment: @Stu I remember seeing Fthiella's answer here earlier, he removed it?

Comment: Seems like it (can't check, don't have enough rep to see deleted answers). It too worked for one level, or two if expanded. I wish he'd left it up though, the thought process was not bad at all.

Comment: @stu oh i just come back to this question and i saw your comments... yes i deleted my answer because i realized it was not working and i didn't know how to fix it... but i just read on meta that it's fine to leave wrong answers, but it's better to put a disclaimer.. if you're interested i can undelete it

Answer (score 0):

I gave this a shot (and spent far too much time on it). Thought I had a solution - it produces the expected results (not exact, but I believe acceptable) for the given data. Unfortunately, it doesn't hold up when more data is added.

Perhaps someone else can find a working solution based on this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.`owner`, a.`attribute`, a.`value`, a.`index` * b.`index` AS `Rule_No`
FROM (
  SELECT `owner`, `attribute`, `value`,  
    IF(
      `owner` = @_owner AND `attribute` = @_attribute,
      @_row := @_row + 1,
      @_row := 1 AND (@_owner := `owner`) AND (@_attribute := `attribute`)
    ) + 1 AS `index`
  FROM `attributes`, (SELECT @_owner := '', @_attribute := '', @_row := 0) x
  ORDER BY `owner`, `attribute`
  ) a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT `owner`, `attribute`, `value`,  
    IF(
      `owner` = @_owner AND `attribute` = @_attribute,
      @_row := @_row + 1,
      @_row := 1 AND (@_owner := `owner`) AND (@_attribute := `attribute`)
    ) + 1 AS `index`
  FROM `attributes`, (SELECT @_owner := '', @_attribute := '', @_row := 0) x
  ORDER BY `owner`, `attribute`
  ) b
ON a.`owner` = b.`owner` AND a.`attribute` <> b.`attribute`
ORDER BY `owner`, `Rule_No`, `attribute`, `value`
```

[SQLFiddle - Working](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0626e/1)

[SQLFiddle - Broken (More Data Added)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a543/1)

Answer (score 0):

While this is far from complete, it was the best I could do in the time I had. Maybe it will give somebody else an idea? It gets the right row counts in the wrong order for this data set, specifically.

```
select a.owner, a.attribute, a.value
from test1 a
    join (
        select owner, attribute, count(distinct attribute, value) - 1 as total
        from test1
        group by owner, attribute
    ) b
        on a.owner = b.owner
            and a.attribute = b.attribute
    join (
        select owner, max(total) as total from (
            select owner, attribute, count(distinct attribute, value) as total
            from test1
            group by owner, attribute
        ) t group by owner
    ) c
        on a.owner = c.owner
    join (
        select @rownum:=@rownum+1 as num
        from test1,
            (select @rownum:=0 from dual) r
    ) temp
        on num <= c.total - b.total
order by a.owner asc
;
```